# Facebook Share cache busting to see specified image pull through in the preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, header, meta-tags

I have read a few thread about Facebook caching the results on your page and also that the [Object Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) will flush this cache if you enter your URL and hit "Fetch New Scrape Information".

I have added this meta tag to the body (so not in the `<head>`) of my document and the image definitely exists, but the 'Share' feature still shows random images in the preview.

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ayrshireminis.com/mini/images/ambanner.jpg" />`

Does the OpenGraph meta tags need to be in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that, yes, you need to inject it into `<head>`.

I do this:

```
// inject the Facebook OpenGraph image into the header to allow the FB share functionality to pull in a more relevant image
var main_image = $('.main_image').attr('src');
if (main_image) {
    $('head').append("<meta property='og:image' content='" + main_image + "' />");
}
```